# How would I use JSP to write directly to a separate HTML page?

Tags: html, jsp

I was requested to built this project in JSP and one stipulation is that this project cannot have a database.  I am trying to write a JSP form to allow users to add, remove and edit links on a separate HTML page.  I have very, very limited JSP experience and I was hoping that someone could point me to a decent tutorial.  I would greatly appreciate some direction. I am relatively comfortable with JavaScript, JQuery and the DOM in general.

Comment: So the idea is that the HTML page is a static HTML file, and your JSP should result in editing that file so that the HTML is permanently changed?  If so, is there any possibility that two users will be trying to edit the page at the same time?

Comment: There is only one person that would be changing the page so currently it would not be possible that two users would try to edit the page at the same time.  In the future, I find it highly, highly unlikely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a fullworthy SQL database server is not an option for some reason, then you can always use an *embedded* SQL database server, like [JavaDB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javadb/index.html), [H2](http://www.h2database.com) or [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org). It that is also even not an option, then you can always head to a textbased file in a predefinied format like CSV, XML or even JSON. There are lot of tools available which can convert between Java objects and CSV, XML and JSON. Even more, it's relatively easy to homegrow it. If that is even not an option for some odd reason, then you can as last resort use [Java serialization](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/serialization/spec/serialTOC.html).

At least, HTML is definitely not a suitable format for "data storage".

Comment: I completely agree that HTML is not a suitable format for data storage.  I wasn't trying to store data via HTML.  I have a simple web page containing nothing more than links.  I wanted to allow the users to edit the links.  I was asked to write it in JSP.  I thought I could write to XML with the JSP form and read the XML form using JQuery and display it via HTML; I was hoping to cut out the middleman and write directly to the HTML page.

Thank you for your response.

Comment: If your concrete problem is that you don't know where to get started with JSP/Servlets, I'd suggest to concentrate you on learning JSP (the view) and Servlets (the controller) first. You can get started on [About JSP](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsp/info) and [About Servlets](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) pages here. In JSP you can embed HTML/CSS/JS and dynamically inline server-side variables by taglibs/EL. In Servlet you can intercept on HTTP requests and write freely Java code to handle the request and the response.